# Rounding double to int using math class

Tags: java, math, rounding

I've been trying to make the `unitTotal`(double) into an integer by using the rounding method, then assigning the integer to the mark variable. I have been stuck on this question and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. If anyone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong it'd be appreciated. Thank you

```
public class GradeCalculator {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double unitTotal;
    int mark;
    String grade; 

    System.out.println("Enter your unit total score");
    unitTotal = sc.nextDouble();
    Math.round(unitTotal); 

    mark = unitTotal;
```

Comment: Is the code you've shared complete?

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the rounding result to the variable:

```
mark = (int) Math.round(unitTotal);
```

Do note that `Math` class suggests to round `double` to `long`. By casting to `int` you are potentially loosing precision.

Comment: I finally get it, it makes so much sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sc.nextFloat();` instead. Then you can use [`Math.round(float a)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-) that returns `int` and assign it to `mark`:

```
mark = Math.round(sc.nextFloat());
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is a method for rounding a double to the nearest whole number then I have an idea, though it's not using a library method.

```
public int round(double value) {
    int cutDecimals = (int) value;  // This cuts the decimals entirely, rounding down
    double decimals = value - ((double) cutDecimals);  // Gives only the decimals
    if(decimals < 0.5) return cutDecimals;  // If the decimals is less than 0.5 we return the rounded down number
    else return cutDecimals + 1;  // If the decimals is over 0.5 we round up
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double)), `Math.round` method returns `long` when passing value is `double` and returns `int` when passing value is `float`.

Change type of `mark` to `long` or you need to convert `long` into `int` manually. Keep in mind that it could throw an exception if return value is more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Also, you need to store return value into variable.

```
 Math.round(unitTotal);
```

replace with

```
 mark = Math.round(unitTotal);
```

HTH.